# Transform a MongoDb parent reference tree into a deep nested tree

Tags: scala, tree, mongodb

Given a mongodb collection that stores trees as nodes with parent references this methods returns a deep nested tree where every child nodes are stored in a property childs[Seq]

```
  def getTree(rootId: BSONObjectID): Future[CategoryTreeNode] = {

    def collect(parent: CategoryTreeNode): Future[CategoryTreeNode] = {

      // Query the database - returns a Future[Seq[CategoryTreeNode]]
      getChilds(parent._id.get).map {

        // Seq[CategoryTreeNode]
        childs =>
          Future.sequence(
            childs.map(child => collect(child)) // Recursion
          ).map(childSeq => parent.copy(childs = Some(childSeq)))

      }.flatMap(x => x).map(y => y) 

    }

    // Find the root node and start the recursion
    findOne[CategoryTreeNode](Json.obj("_id" -> rootId)).map(maybeNode => maybeNode match {
      case None => throw new RuntimeException("Current node not found by id!")
      case Some(node) => collect(node)
    }).flatMap(x => x)

  }
```

Comment: What are your concerns about the code? Or do you simply want general comments about your implementation?

Comment: Basically I want to know if it can be done better/more idiomatic - especially the map.flatmap cascades look odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `flatMap (x => x)` would probably better be written as `flatten`.
- `map (x => x)` is essentially a no-op, and could be removed.
- `map ( ... ) flatten` is equivalent to `flatMap (...)`
- It doesn't seem useful to put a type into a comment – you can specify the type for parameters of lambdas as well:

  ```
  { (childs: Seq[CategoryTreeNode]) => ...
  ```

  However, this style is generally discouraged. It would be more useful to store the future from the DB in a variable which gets typed explicitly.
- Higher-order method like `map` should not be invoked with a leading `.`: do `collection map (x => ...)` instead of `collection.map(x => ...)` ([source](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#higherorder_functions)).
- `(foo => foo match { ... })` can be simplified to `(_ match { ... })`
- `(child => collect(child))` can be simplified to `(collect(_))` or even just `collect`

Together, I'd clean up your code to this:

```
def getTree(rootId: BSONObjectID): Future[CategoryTreeNode] = {
  def collect(parent: CategoryTreeNode): Future[CategoryTreeNode] = {
    // Query the database
    val ourChilds: Future[Seq[CategoryTreeNode]] = getChilds(parent._id.get)
    ourChilds flatMap { childs =>
      Future.sequence(childs map collect) map { childSeq =>
        parent.copy(childs = Some(childSeq))
      }
    }
  }

  // Find the root node and start the recursion
  findOne[CategoryTreeNode](Json.obj("_id" -> rootId)) flatMap (_ match {
    case None => throw new RuntimeException("Current node not found by id!")
    case Some(node) => collect(node)
  })
}
```